Moving from Ubuntu Desktop to WSL
So yeah, I wanna go back to Windows for reasons that are completely out of my hands. But I still cannot even dare to develop my projects in CMD or Powershell, I need to use Ubuntu WSL.
So, my question is: How do I move from Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu WSL without having to redo/reconfigure a lot of stuff?
I think moving the home directory alone is not enough, so anyone got any idea out there?
For clarification:
I don't think I care about GUI applications since running GUI from WSL is weird. I want to move over any system configurations that can matter in WSL (so not thing like grub, which are non-existent in WSL), my nodejs and npm versions, etcetera.

In order for anyone (not me, I have 0 knowledge of WSL) to be able to answer, you will need to specify what kind of things you want to migrate. Migrating GUI is a different thing to migrating just data, for example. Do you need to keep the same user? Passwords? Installed applications? What kind of applications? Please [edit]  and clarify.

@terdon Done, I edited the question

Unfortunately there's not going to be a great way to do this.  I can think of two (and a half) possible options.

Obviously, manually

Back up the Ubuntu installation in a form where you can easily access the files.  This is probably going to be something like an rsync to an external device.  Verify the backup.

Set up Ubuntu on WSL, start installing the things you know you want, and then move over the configuration files (and data, if applicable) for those items.  You can probably just start by restoring your home directory, yes. That will get you some of the way there.
Expect that you'll probably get a lot of errors initially. If you find that you can't boot into your user profile on WSL because of errors from missing items, you can always access it via wsl ~ -u root.



Subtractive approach
Not pretty. Work on uninstalling anything graphical on the desktop system to try to turn it (as much as possible) into a "Server" installation.  Then back up the system, as root (in single-user mode) using tar and wsl --import that.
There's a lot of hand-waving here.  Not tested, and I'd prefer the "Manual" version personally.

Option "and-a-half".  Use a VM on Windows for starters.  This should allow you to migrate from the desktop to Windows more easily.  Set up WSL2 and start the "Manual" migration while you have a functioning VM in the meantime.



Then I will back up my home directory only because I'm limited on storage, but where are configuration files generally stored beside the home directory? If it's not worth much extra storage, I'll back them up too!

$ cd; ls -lA will show you many of the config directories. FWIW; For What It's Worth: I believe that a VM in either of Virtualbox or VMWare is a better option than the "non-standard" WSL - a VM vill work "exactly" as the Linux, no quirks or limitations.

@Proman4713 Config files for system-level software are typically in /etc
